# ng-class - finding a value inside object

Tags: angularjs, javascript-objects, ng-class

I have an object that looks like this:

```
$scope.things = [
    {
        name: 'Bob!',
        short_name: 'bob',
        info: 'something something'
    },
    {
        name: 'Steve',
        short_name: 'steve',
        info: 'something something something'
    },
];
```

I loop through them like this and add an ng-click:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-click="addThing(thing.name, thing.short_name, thing_info" ng-class="thingClass(thing.name)">content goes here</div>
```

the `ng-click="addThing()"` basically bunches up the values and adds them to the object.

When clicked, it should add the class `selected` - this worked fine and dandy when I wasn't using a multidimensional object, because it was simply looking for `name` inside the object / array (at this point, I think it's an object... but at the time, it was an array)

I can't work out how to do the equivalent to this...

```
$scope.thingClass= function(name) {
    if($scope.thingSelected.indexOf(name) != -1) {
        return 'selected';
    }
};
```

...with the object as it now stands. I've tried to adapt a few answers from here that I found through google, such as:

```
$scope.teamClass = function(name) {

    var found = $filter('filter')($scope.thingSelected, {id: name}, true);

    if (found.length) {
        return 'selected';
    }

};
```

...but with no joy.

Can anyone point / nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Is `$scope.thingSelected` one of the objects in the `$scope.things`?

Comment: typo here `ng-click="addThing(thing.name, thing.short_name, thing.info)"`

Comment: what is `$scope.thingSelected` ?? is it an array of objects, holding each object added, or is it an array ??

Comment: Please give a plunker. typo in function call and adding class are not done correctly

Comment: wero, yes - it's not 100% clear there but I use $scope.things to create a list of items (with ng-repeat), if an item is clicked, it is both added to $scope.thingSelected and should also mark that item by adding a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply pass the thing object to `thingClass`:

```
... ng-class="thingClass(thing)" ...
```

and implement `thingClass` as follows:

```
$scope.thingClass= function(thing) {
    return $scope.thingSelected.indexOf(thing) >= 0 ? 'selected' : '';
}
```

And maybe your should apply this technique to `addThing` also:

```
... ng-click="addThing(thing)" ...

$scope.addThing = function(thing) {
    if ($scope.thingSelected.indexOf(thing) < 0)
        $scope.thingSelected.push(thing);
}
```

But instead of tracking the selected things in an array its much easier to introduce a `selected` property in each thing:

```
$scope.addThing = function(thing) {
    thing.selected = true;
}

$scope.thingClass= function(thing) {
    return thing.selected ? 'selected' : '';
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, I was under the impression I couldn't just pass an entire object over like that, not sure where I got that impression from (something unrelated going wrong probably)... some re-writes are needed I think, thank you